# Determing which element was clicked

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a html like:

```
<div class="clicked-div" onclick="divClicked(this);">
    <img src="src1"/>
    <img src="src2"/>
    ......
</div>
```

if I set the img onclick event using the following method:

```
       var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
          imgs[i].onClick=imageClicked(imgs[i]);
        }
      function divClicked(div){
            alert(div.getAttribute("id"));
        }

        function imageClicked(image){
            alert(image.getAttribute("src"));
        }
```

when the uiwebview load one image, it will call imageClicked a time though I haven't click it.
And when I click a image ,how do I determing which method will be called divClicked or  imageClicked? THank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is **calling** `imageClicked` at the point you're trying to just set it up as a handler.

It's actually easier than you think it is:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = imageClicked;  // <=== Not *calling*, just referring to it
}
function imageClicked() {
    alert(this.getAttribute("src")); // <== `this` rather than `image`
}
```

When `imageClicked` is called in response to the click event, it's called with `this` set to the image element that was clicked.

> How to prevent the div to handle the click event when the image was clicked

Instead of `onclick`, you use modern event handling and stop propagation. As you're using a uiWebView, you don't have to worry about old IE, which makes things simpler:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener("click", imageClicked, false);
}
function imageClicked(e) {
    alert(this.getAttribute("src"));
    e.stopPropagation();  // <=== Prevents the click reaching the div
}
```

**Live example:**

```js
// Hook up the divs so we handle clicks on them
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].onclick = divClicked;  // <=== Not *calling*, just referring to it
}
function divClicked() {
    alert("div clicked");
}

// The images code
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener("click", imageClicked, false);
}
function imageClicked(e) {
    alert(this.getAttribute("src"));
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2cd48a51689add31036ce202cc020255?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/760b4da77fd54d37c104029ff1f56749?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
<div>
  No image in this one, so you can see it handle clicks
</div>
```

---

Side note: Although you can use `onClick` in your HTML, when you're using it in JavaScript, it **has** to be `onclick` (all lower case). I've made that change above in the version that still used it.